# Where do I store my non-private data in a React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, backend, e-commerce

So I'm trying to make a full website for the first time, e-commerce. Of course the user data should be stored in database, and reached by a backend like nodejs. But what about the non-private data, like all the products.

Is there any difference between having all the products as an object inside my react code, in a like Product.js file vs Having all the products on the server, and fetch them ? Which one is recommended ?

One difference I can think of is, fetching them from database would make the initial load of the website faster, since the user isn't downloading all the data until they visit products page. But that can be achieved with react's built in lazy loading anyways.

So which one of those is recommended ? And why ? Thanks.

option1- Keep products as object in frontend. And use lazy loading so user doesn't download all products only if they visit products page, instead of the initial visit.

option2- Fetch them from database to frontend directly. Normally bad practice but; from a whole different, second database. The firebase database for example. The other database (mongodb) which has private data will never be accessed from the front-end.

option3- Fetch them from database -> to backend -> to frontend. I'm guessing this approach isn't good because it would make the load quite slow ?

Comment: If you keep everything on the front end, how will you add a new item when you need? Will you keep releasing the app? `Separation of concerns` is a big deal in software.  So avoid option 1. In an ecomm site, there will be another admin site where someone add those products. So you will need another site for that usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 is likely the best for your use case. The additional latency incurred by going through the backend server is going to be negligible at worst, possibly a couple of milliseconds (provided the database and backend server are closely located, i.e. within the same datacentre).

A public firestore instance could work well, however there doesn't seem to be any good reason to complicate the stack and have two databases. If you are going to use a mongodb database anyway, you may as well commit to this route. Exposing your data via an API running on a backend server is always preferable in this case. In the simplest case, you would just have API routes returning the data in the "products" table. However in the future the advantages of this approach will show, for example; what if you want to restrict certain products to a release date, prevent certain users from seeing specific products. Both of these examples could be achieved through access-control managed by your backend server, acting as a "gatekeeper" to the data held within your database. Likewise you can implement rate limiting etc.

You could make use of Next.js or some other SSR (server-side rendering) technology to pre-render the page with product information embedded within the initial HTML document. This would save you the second round trip time after page load. It would also mean google search, embedded links in apps like twitter messenger etc would have the correct product metadata to display in the preview.

**Normal AJAX request:**

```
           HTTP GET
Client ------------------> Frontend Server
            HTML                  |
Client <------------------ Frontend Server
        products_request
Client ------------------> Backend Server
                                  |          database query
                           Backend Server ------------------> mongodb
                                             product_data        |
                           Backend Server <------------------ mongodb
        products_data             |
Client <------------------ Backend Server
```

**Next.js:**

```
           HTTP GET
Client ------------------> Frontend Server
                                  |
                                  |
                                  | products_request
                                  |
                                  V          database query
                           Backend Server ------------------> mongodb
                                             product_data        |
                           Backend Server <------------------ mongodb
                                  |
                                  | products_data
          HTML page               V
Client ------------------> Frontend Server
```

I would point you [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/node-express-mongodb-crud-rest-api/) for a more in-depth Node.js, Express, Mongodb tutorial if that is the stack you want to use.